# How to override / overwrite built-in Alexa skill invocation names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to overwrite the built-in Alexa function that responds to the command: "Alexa, where am I?". I have chosen "Where am I" as the invocation name of my skill, but currently I have to say "Alexa, open 'where am I'" for the launchRequest to run. Saying "Alexa, where am I" causes Alexa to state my location.

I have tried renaming my Invocation name to use a capital W ("Where am I") but I still have to say "open" before my Invocation Name for the skill to work.

The skill connects to a Lambda function, but the Lambda does not use the invocation name anywhere because it's linked to the skill anyway. This is why I assume a change must be made in the skill-builder.

What's the best way to achieve this override?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that *"Where am I?"* may be a reserved phrase that can't be used for an invocation without an action?  [*"The invocation name must not create confusion with existing Alexa features."*](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/choose-the-invocation-name-for-a-custom-skill.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, I think I am asking the impossible here. Time to think of a new invocation name.